# Is there anyway that I can give a div a function in p5.js

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

Im trying to take a div that I created and make it move across the screen every hour using p5.js and I'm wondering if that is at all possible I was also wonderig if that div can change color randomly every hour in p5.js

Comment: I'm not familiar with P5.js, however, couldn't you just use a normal JavaScript timer that calls your draw function every hour? Such as, [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use the [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) function. With this function, we can perform the animation every hour. However, one problem which arises is that, according to the [P5.js documentation,](http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/draw) the `draw()` function executes continuously after the `setup()` function is called. We can fix this by taking advantage of the `noLoop()` and `loop` functions.

The `noLoop()` function call will stop the `draw()` function from executing and the `loop()` function will start the execution again. So, let's take a look at how we can code this:

**Note:** According to the documentation, there can only be one draw function for each sketch. So, if you have other things animating throughout the course of the hour this approach may not be the best choice.

```
//stores the position of the element on the x-axis of the screen
var xPos = 0;
var delay = 60000 * 60; //1,000 milliseconds in a second

window.setInterval(function(){
    //code to be called every hour; make draw function loop
    loop();
}, delay);

function setup(){
    //create your canvas or div or whatever
    createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw(){
    // clear the current background
    background(255);

    // set the fill color of your element
    fill(255, 0, 0);

    //change the x position so it can move across the screen
    xPos = xPos + 1;

    // if the circle moves off screen, it's finished animating for the hour
    if(xpos > width)
    {
        xPos = 0; //reset back to 0;
        noLoop(); //end the looping of the draw function        
    }

    //draw your element to the correct location and size; here I'll use an ellipse
     ellipse(xPos, 100, 25, 25);

}
```

I'm not the most familiar with P5.js as I've stated but hopefully this gives you enough an idea to get it working.

**Edit:** An alternative approach would be to use CSS animations. With CSS animations you wouldn't even need P5.js to get your desired effect.

HTML:

```
<div id="my-div" class="my-div"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-div {
    /* animation name followed by how long the animation takes to perform */
    /* browser prefixes for more browser support */
    animation: slide-across-screen 1s;
    -webkit-animation: slide-across-screen 1s;
    -moz-animation: slide-across-screen 1s;
}

@keyframes slide-across-screen {
    0% {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    100% {
        margin-left: 100%;
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var div = document.getElementById("my-div");
div.addEventListener("animationend", function(){
    div.style.marginLeft = 0;
    div.style.animationPlayState = paused;
}

window.setInterval(function(){
    div.style.animationPlayState = running; //might need browser prefixes here as well
}, 60000 * 60);
```

Comment: how do i get the <div> that i created to move across the screen everyhour cause im not trying to get a circle to move across

Comment: @MarjorieChamberlain it's the same idea just with a little alteration. There seems to be no "natural" support in P5.js but this can be done with JavaScript. Make the element relative: `div.style.position = relative;`. Then in the draw() function change the ellipse() function call to: `div.style.left = xPos;`. Also, keep in mind that a `div` is a block level element, so you may consider changing it to an inline-block.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the createDiv() element from the p5.dom.js addon library. http://p5js.org/reference/#/libraries/p5.dom

```
var x = 0;
var myDiv;

function setup() {
  var myDiv = createDiv("This is my DIV!");
  setInterval(function() {
    x+=100;
    myDiv.position(x, 200);
  }, 60*60*1000);
}
```

Comment: Could you please add more details about the solution you provide?